# Lognormal Distribution Probability

Tags: probability, distributions, lognormal-distribution

I'm dealing with this question, and i didn't understand should i use the $f(x)$ formula for lognormal distribution or can i calculate it with $z(P)$? Thank you for help.  And i've found probability $1.$ If anyone can solve the question i'll be appreciated. Thanks.

Question: A person arrives at a certain bus stop each morning. The waiting time, in minutes, for a bus to arrive is log normally distributed with $5$ min mean and $1$ min standard deviation. Suppose that waiting times on different mornings are independent. What is the probability that the waiting time is less than $4$ minutes on at least $2$ of $10$ mornings?

$$
z(P) = \frac{x-\text{mean}}{\text{standard deviation}}
$$
(Used with Z table)

[image]

Comment: It's hard to answer the question without knowing what f(x) and z(P) are :)

Comment: Evidently you will need to find the chance that the waiting time on any given morning is less than 4 minutes, so begin with that calculation.

Comment: I edited the question. But what is the probability of less than 4. I calculate that with z(p)  because the integral of f(x) is too hard. But a friend of mine said, i can't do that part with z(p) from the normal distribution.

Comment: "5  min mean and 1 min standard deviation" $\mu = 5, \sigma = 1$ or $E(x) = 5, Var(x) = 1$? symbols follow that pdf.